Keyboard is getting dismissed after typing one character in the search bar
First I enter some text in the search bar controller, it works fine. Next I delete the text and retype the same text or different text. In this case the keyboard is getting dismissed immediately after typing every character in the search bar.
The delegate method which I have implemented for the search bar :
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
    
    filteredData = []  // Clear the filteredData array
   
    if searchText == "" {
        filteredData = data
    }
    
    for item in data {
        if item.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) {
            filteredData.append(item)
        }
    }
   
    selectionTableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
}

if any help is greatly appreciated.Thanks

This looks like a programming-related question and is more suitable for stack overflow.

You need to stop saying becomeFirstResponder. By definition, if you receive a call to textDidChange or textDidBeginEditing, the search bar is first responder.

The searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) method is being called every time the text changes in the search bar. In this method, you're calling searchBar.becomeFirstResponder() unconditionally, which could be causing the keyboard to dismiss unexpectedly.
Remove searchBar.becomeFirstResponder() from searchBar(_:textDidChange:). This method should not handle keyboard visibility directly unless you have a specific reason to ensure the keyboard is always visible.
If you need to ensure the keyboard stays visible during editing, use searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_:) method to become first responder instead.
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    filteredData = []

    if searchText.isEmpty {
        filteredData = data
    } else {
        filteredData = data.filter { $0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) }
    }

    selectionTableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    // You may not need to call becomeFirstResponder here if the default behavior is sufficient so comment below line.
    // searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
}

